# How to find partitions that go to same node?

Tags: apache-spark

Say that I've a `HashPartioner` and I use it to partition 2 RDDs. Now, if those two RDDs have some common values, they will end up in the same node as they're partitioned by the same partitioner. What I'd like to do is finding those partitions.

In another words, how can I find partitions of 2 RDDs that end up in the same node when partitioned by the same partitioner ?

Comment: An RDD, when well-partitioned, should end up on every node.

Comment: @JoeC What do you mean? I'm partitioning them using the same HashPartitioner. How could same values might end up in different nodes ?

Comment: An RDD consists of multiple values.  While a single value will exist on a single node, the RDD will be spread across the entire cluster.

Comment: @JoeC Your first statement is not necessarily true. It depends on the data, the cluster, and what you're hoping to accomplish. In fact, that's why we `coalesce` our `RDDs` sometimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method I was looking for was zipPartitions().

Answer (score 1):

I do two things. First, one trick I like to use--particularly when I am experimenting--is `glom`. This is a method on `RDD` that expresses it as an `Array[Array]]`. Each inner array represents a partition. So when I am in the Spark shell or writing a quick driver program to experiment, I find `glom` helpful to reason about the effect of my partitioning strategy and how it is maintained or changed over the course of my transformations.

Then if I care to know which node has which partition(s), I consult my resource manager--typically Mesos, Yarn, or Spark Standalone--to see those details.

Comment: Hi, Could you please elaborate on the last point that you mentioned "to know which node has which partition(s), I consult resource manager ". I would like to see this information but looks like I am missing something. How can I see the partitions of a particular dataframe on nodes within YARN?  A screenshot would be helpful.